# Lumia 640 email client

Tags: email, lumia-640-xl

I've just had my work phone upgraded to a Lumia 640, which is proving ok so far, however the one thing that is annoying me is the email client. I am restricted to default client by corporate policy and use of exchange so no way of using another app, although is there a way to personalize the default client instead?

Three things are annoying me that I would like to fix:

1. Senders name appearing at the top in big letters at the top of every email. (I know who wrote to me without having it in massive letters!) Can this be made smaller or normal size somehow?
2. Moving mail to a folder. My old blackberry was great for this as you would press "file" and it would automatically suggest a folder or you could just start typing the folder name. As I have umpteen sub folders I now have to have to spend 30 seconds or so scrolling through numerous levels to find the right place whereas before it took less than 3!
3. The big typeface headers "All", "flagged", "unread" etc in the inbox. I would either like to make these smaller or preferably remove them and default to "all" without need to change between

Apologies for the rant, other than this I am fairly impressed so far!!